# Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 - mount a windows share issue

Tags: rhel, windows, cifs

Already  both share and NTFS permissions Everyone - Full control for `//10.180.102.11/Data`.

I have already setting up share `//10.180.102.11/Data` under file server domain joined.

I want to access all subdirectories & files under `//10.180.102.11/Data/IT_Folder/Projects`.

```
mount -t cifs //10.180.102.11/Data/IT_Folder/Projects /share -o username=guest,password="",vers=1.0
```

I am getting  `NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Do I need to instal something else? Do I need to configure something?

LAST UPDATE :

```
 SMB Session Authentication Failure

Client Name: \\xx.xx.xx.xx
Client Address: xx.xx.xx.xx:40006
User Name: 
Session ID: 0x204029000002D
Status: The user account has been automatically locked because too many invalid logon attempts or password change attempts have been requested. (0xC0000234)
SPN: session setup failed before the SPN could be queried
SPN Validation Policy: SPN optional / no validation

Guidance:

You should expect this error when attempting to connect to shares using incorrect credentials.

This error does not always indicate a problem with authorization, but mainly authentication. It is more common with non-Windows clients.

This error can occur when using incorrect usernames and passwords with NTLM, mismatched LmCompatibility settings between client and server, an incorrect service principal name, duplicate Kerberos service principal names, incorrect Kerberos ticket-granting service tickets, or Guest accounts without Guest access enabled
```

Comment: I have  edited my question. btw , already smbv1 & smbv2 enabled on file server. Also I catched something inside  event viewer.  you can see my above last update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do is to use a valid username and password, the second is to stop using the obsolete SMB v1.

Try something like this, replacing `contoso.com` with your AD domain, `realuser` with a real valid username, and `whatever` with the corresponding password. I have used SMB v3.0 in this example as all supported Windows servers handle this directly.

```
mount -t cifs //10.180.102.11/Data/IT_Folder/Projects /share -o 'domain=contoso.com,username=realuser,password=whatever,vers=3.0'
```

Once this works, I strongly recommend you moving the credentials out of the command line and into a secure file. The password is still stored in clear text but at least it's not in a publicly readable file

```
cat >/etc/smb_credentials <<'EOF'
domain=contoso.com
username=realuser
password=whatever
EOF

chown root:root /etc/smb_credentials
chmod 600 /etc/smb_credentials          # user: read/write, group+others: no access

mount -t cifs //10.180.102.11/Data/IT_Folder/Projects /share -o 'credentials=/etc/smb_credentials,vers=3.0'
```